# thmtools - Theorem does not change the title when I change the command that defines it

Tags: amsthm, thmtools

Here is the example of a code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newcommand\testTitle{Theorem}

\declaretheorem[title = \testTitle]{thm}

\renewcommand\testTitle{The theorem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{thm}
        This is a theorem.
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

This code gives me the following output.

[image]

The output I'm expecting is:

[image]

Is there a way to use `thmtools` to define a theorem with a redefinable name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome! A quick (and dirty, maybe) way of achieving what you want is to `\protect` the title from being expanded before you want this to happen. (I also use the `name` key but it works with `title`, too. According to the manual, `name` seems to a bit more versatile.)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newcommand\testTitle{Theorem}

\declaretheorem[name=\protect\testTitle]{thm}


\renewcommand\testTitle{The theorem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{thm}
        This is a theorem.
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why does your code not give you what you want? Because the value of `title` gets expanded when you say

```
\declaretheorem[title = \testTitle]{thm}
```

With `\protect`, i.e.

```
 \declaretheorem[title =\protect\testTitle]{thm}
```

you prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 6):

A complement to [Schrödinger's cat fine answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536867/4427).

Try and comment out the definition of `\testTitle`. When you run LaTeX over the example, you'll receive

```latex
! Undefined control sequence.
\thmt@thmname ->\testTitle

l.8 \declaretheorem[title = \testTitle]{thm}
```

Oh, weird, isn't it? If you try the same with just `amsthm` features, with

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{\testTitle}
\newcommand\testTitle{Theorem}

\renewcommand\testTitle{The theorem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{thm}
        This is a theorem.
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

you'll see no problem. Note that the position of `\newcommand{\testTitle}{...}` is irrelevant.

What's the difference? With `amsthm` (or the default `\newtheorem` of the LaTeX kernel), no expansion is performed. On the contrary, `\declaretheorem` performs expansion on the value given to `title` (or its alias `name`).

It would happen similarly with `ntheorem`, by the way.

How do you solve the issue? Use `\protect` in front of the “symbolic name”. And no, a single `\noexpand` will not suffice. Since `thmtools` uses `\protected@edef` for doing its job, this `\protect` will be changed into an “infinite `\noexpand`”; however, when typesetting the text, `\protect` is the same as `\relax`, so it does no harm.